# What are the rules for creating multiple syllable words in Tibetan without tsheg?

Tags: syllables, tibetan

I was under the assumption that **all** Tibetan syllables were marked with a [tsheg](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tsheg), but now after talking with someone from Tibet, I learn that there are many cases where this is not true, such as [pema](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E0%BD%94%E0%BD%91%E0%BE%A8) (`པདྨ`, notice, no tsheg, but two syllables technically).

I will also note that they said:

> Pema can be written in two ways, like པད་མ། and པདྨ།.

So one way *does* have the tsheg, but the other doesn't. There are many other examples of this. So (a) why isn't it always marked with a tsheg? And (b) how can I tell where the syllable boundary is without the tsheg, are there some rules to determine it or is it more a human-interpretation task that is hard to define (especially hard to define for automatically determining syllable boundaries via a computer)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first assumption is largely correct. Native Tibetan words regularly employ the ཚེག་ *tsheg* (intersyllabic dot) to separate their syllables. However, loanwords, especially those from Sanskrit (henceforth abbreviated Skt.), were sometimes spelled without the *tsheg* in traditional orthography. I ignore the reason behind such convention, but I would not say this kind of spelling without the *tsheg* is particularly frequent, as it is mainly seen in words that have a religious connotation, at least as far as I am aware. See for example terms like བུདྡྷ་ *buddha* "Buddha" (< Skt. बुद्ध​ *buddha*), པདྨ་ *padma* "lotus" (< Skt. पद्म​ *padma*) and ཤུབྷཾ་ *shubhaṃ* "auspicious" (< Skt. शुभ *śubha-*), or entire phrases taken from Sanskrit, such as the first line of the *Divine Tree Grammar poem*: ནམོ་གུརུ་མཉྫུ་གྷོཥཱ་ཡ། *namo guru mandzu ghoṣ'a ya* "I bow down to my teacher Mañjughoṣa (see [Mañjuśrī](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manjushri))" (from Skt. नमोगुरुमञ्जुघोषाय​​ *namo guru Mañjughoṣāya*).

So, to answer your questions, (a) words that are of Tibetan origin follow normal orthographic rules, which prescribe that syllables must be separated by means of a *tsheg*, but (b) words of foreign origin (i.e. Sanskrit borrowings) are occasionally exempted from this rule, and can be written without *tsheg*s separating their syllables. Therefore, in order to know which words admit this alternative spelling without the *tsheg*, you have to be familiar with their etymology.